# Dependency with json and select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a json:

```
{
    "A": {
        "1": "1",
        "2": "2",
        "3": "3"
    }, 
    "B": {
        "4": "4",
        "5": "5",
        "6": "6"
    }, 
    "C": {
        "7": "7",
        "8": "8"
    }
}
```

and two select:

```
<select id="main">
  <option></option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

and:

```
<select id="sub">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
```

I would like, for example:

if i select A in select#main then this should hide 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8 in select#sub

if i select B in select#main then this should hide 1, 2, 3, 7 and 8 in select#sub

if i select C in select#main then this should hide 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 in select#sub

using dependency from json.

How can i make it without use AJAX?

Comment: Your title doesn't have anything to do with the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "AJAX"? You aren't describing any server requests.

Comment: Sorry, i corrected title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use AJAX if you have your object handy:

Try

```
var $sub = $('#sub');
$sub.find('option:gt(0)').remove();
$('#main').on('change', function(){
     var options = opts[this.value];
    $sub.find('option:gt(0)').remove();
    var $this = $(this);
    $sub.append($.map(options, function(i, o){

        return $('<option/>', {value:i, text:o});
    }));
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MhjSy/)**

Comment: perfect, very thanks :) could you modify this code http://jsfiddle.net/MhjSy/1/ to working on start? i set selected to B, but on start this not working

Comment: @rafael3444 this way http://jsfiddle.net/fRpcW/